# pass pip path to python or python path to pip when running install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

python.exe is version 3.6. I have installed python3.8 in another directory and it is searched later in the PATH order after python 3.6.

When running `python3.8 -m pip install package_name`. Can one choose which pip is loaded when running that command.

I have python3.8 installed but i can't rename it to python.exe because python.exe is already python 3.6. So when i just do `pip3.8 install package_name` it uses the python.exe(3.6 version) so i am unable to install the packages for the python 3.8 version.

Comment: `python3.8 -m pip install package_name` should be perfectly fine, and (from what I know) targets the version of PIP associated with that version of Python. [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/